# Swift Animate Constraint in extension

Tags: swift, animation, constraints

Below is the code I use to move and shrink labels. It was working fine until I turned it into an extension. Now the properties animate but not the constraints. I've seen this same question asked several times, but the solutions all seem pretty simple and none are working. I've tried moving the constraint constants as well as `layoutIfNeeded`() above the animation, below the alpha setting, above and below...no luck.

```
extension UIView {
   func moveLabel(lc: NSLayoutConstraint, hc: NSLayoutConstraint) {
      lc.constant = -1
      hc.constant = 24
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
         self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
         self.alpha = 0.5
         self.layoutIfNeeded()
      }, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: These constraints are outside of the label? Can you show the working solution without extension with context to see where are these constraints?

Comment: The code is very similar with one interesting difference. When I wasn't using an extension I called self.view.layoutIfNeeded(). But in my extension I can't reference the view like that. hmmmm...But I can call self.superview.layoutIfNeeded(). And that fixed the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your saying "I use to move and shrink labels" I am suspecting that your problem arises from the fact that you're calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()` on the label itself, which will update constraints within the current view's scope, but moving views needs the superview to be laid out. As a test you can also include `self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` in your animation block, but if you want to be sure, pass the superview of the label to that function and call `layoutIfNeeded()` on that.

```
extension UIView {
    func moveLabel(lc: NSLayoutConstraint, hc: NSLayoutConstraint, superView: UIView) {
      lc.constant = -1
      hc.constant = 24
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
         self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.7, y: 0.7)
         self.alpha = 0.5
         self.layoutIfNeeded()
         superView.layoutIfNeeded()
      }, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

p.s. in your code you're actually not animating the constraints, is that your intention?

Comment: That was it exactly, thank you. And the constraints do animate. I read somewhere that constants are different than properties. They need to be set first and then animated. Whether they're in the closure or not doesn't matter as long as layoutIfNeeded() is called after they've been set.